# Selenium parse Google Chrome Safebrowsing page

Tags: c#, selenium, google-chrome

I'm writing a software which visits a website and saves a screenshot as well as the innerHTML.
When visiting phishing-sites, Google Chrome's Safe browsing warning shall be saved as well.
But when I navigate to the phishing test page of https://testsafebrowsing.appspot.com/, I can't parse innerHTML. I also tried to simply send STRG-A and STRG-C, but this doesn't work neither.

Do you have any idea on this? I just don't get the contents of the warning page..

code snippet:

```
opt.AddUserProfilePreference("download.prompt_for_download", true);
opt.AddUserProfilePreference("profile.default_content_settings.popups", false);
opt.AddArguments("--user-data-dir="+Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables("%USERPROFILE%\\Appdata\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data"));
opt.AddArguments("disable-infobars"); automatic" 
opt.AddArgument("no-sandbox");

ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(opt);
driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitWait = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20);
driver.Manage().Timeouts().PageLoad = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20);
string url = "https://testsafebrowsing.appspot.com/s/phishing.html"
driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(url);
string html = driver.PageSource;
File.WriteAllText(fileName, html);
```

Comment: do u use same domain if you use a crossdomain the innerHtml will not parse

Comment: Please post the code samples directly here and do not use external links for that. It helps the readers and also ensure the information is kept if the link gets broken in the future.

Comment: Done ;-) Sorry, new to stackoverflow

Comment: if you look at dev tools > net tab, you will notice that browser never navigates to https://testsafebrowsing.appspot.com/s/phishing.html - that request is shown as "pending", and page source (on elements tab) will still show the source of the previous page (if there's one). So what you see at that point is not web page, but a browser overlay, which looks like a webpage, but is not one, it didn't get created by navigation, and has no page source. I guess your best bet in this case is actually lack of navigation to specified page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Kiril S. my problem is solved - the Request is shown as "pending" - so I just tried to parse the driver.Url, which shows the currently active URL - in this case the page I visited before.
This is enough for my use case. Thanks ;-)